# Angular how to set scope variable from service in right way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I would like return value from service method into scope to using and processing in template.

But i found, that i cannot use scope in services. 
I can use Rootscope but i think, that it is not right approach.

How can I easily set value from service into scope?

Thanks for any advice.

Here is code:

```
/**
      * Init autocomplete dropdown menu for project list
      */
     this.getProjectListForAutocomplete =  function (container, options) {
         $("#autocompleteProjects").kendoAutoComplete({
             dataSource :  {
                 type: "json",
                 serverFiltering: true,
                 transport: {
                     read: function (options) {
                         console.log("List");
                         console.log(options.data);

                         ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                             "POST",
                             $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "gpsaddress/search",
                             requestParams
                         )
                             .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                                         break;
                                 }
                             })
                             .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                             });
                     }
                 }
             },
             dataTextField: "city"  ,
             dataValueField: "address.city",
             filter: "contains",
             minLength: 1,
             change  : function (e) {
                 console.log("change");
                 //console.log(e);
             },
             select  : function (e) {
                 console.log("select");
                 var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                 console.log(dataItem);
                 // Here i need set scope in controller
             }
         });
     };
```

Comment: Why don't you make return type method in service  and catch return value in scope in controller ?

Comment: Modifying a scope object in a service would be bad design since controllers are ment to interact with the scope and services are intended to be independent of ui and scope

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Could you please add some example? I'm new in Angular.

Comment: Firstly post your code

Answer (score 4):

Please see demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.service('dataService', function() {

  var _person = {

    name: "jack",
    surname: "doe"

  }

  return {
    person: _person

  }

})
app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

  $scope.person = dataService.person;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
    <p>First Name: {{person.name}}</p>
    <p>Last Name: {{person.surname}}</p>
    Edit First Name:<input type: "text" ng-model="person.name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated question. code where is want to set scope value is nested.

Comment: @redrom I'm bit confused is that code for your controller or service ? And in which place do you want to edit your variable and in which way ?

Comment: Is it code from service method. I need return JSON object into scope in place where is written //// Here i need set scope in controller

Answer (score 1):

**first Method :**

in service :

```
serviceMethod: functon(scope){
   //processing
   scope.scopeVar=data;
}
```

in controller:

```
  service.serviceMethod($scope);
```

when controller call `serviceMethod` of `service`. after processing data is assign to scope.scopeVar.here `scope` refer to  $scope object.(we are passing object $scope to `serviceMethod` method)

**2nd Method-**

in service :

```
serviceMethod: functon(){
   //processing
   returndata;
}
```

in controller:

```
  $scope.scopeVar=service.serviceMethod();
```

Comment: The first method is just bad implementation, and should not be used. Second method is fine. There is a third method which is far too common, where service returns a promise instead of actual data. That example also can be added.

Answer (score 0):

You dont "set-scope-variable-from-service" you BIND to it. Its the same semantic really. @sss is totally correct